# Как сложить ячейки нескольких таблиц, расположенных на разных листах гугл таблиц (apps script)?

Tags: javascript, массивы, google-apps-script

подскажите скрипт для применения математических операций (например, сумма или среднее значение) к ячейкам нескольких таблиц из разных листов, чтобы на выходе получалась одна таблица, с результатом суммы ячеек A1, B1, C1 и т. д. Например:

Лист 1 - значения в диапазоне A1:C1 - 1, 2, 3
Лист 2 - значения в диапазоне A2:C2 - 4, 5, 6
Лист 3 - значения в диапазоне A4:C4 - 7, 8, 9

Результат (Сумма) - 12, 15, 18.

Спасибо.

Comment: Без примера трудно определиться, что вам нужно: (а) пользовательская формула, (б) скрипт в Таблице, (в) скрипт, который создает новую Таблицу, (г) что-то еще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставленная задача обычно решается "в лоб": в первую ячейку результата записывают формулу (следуя Вашему примеру):

```
='Лист1'!A1+'Лист2'!A2+'Лист3'!A4
```

которую затем копируют в следующие справа две колонки. Относительные ссылки при копировании преобразуются так, что получается требуемый результат.

Но есть и более "продвинутый" способ решения, основанный на [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en&ref_topic=3105411). В первую ячейку результата пишем **одну** формулу:

```
=ArrayFormula('Лист1'!A1:C1+'Лист2'!A2:C2+'Лист3'!A4:C4)
```

и нужный результат сразу появляется в трех ячейках.